# How to get just the version of the software when using ansible_facts.packages["zabbix-agent"]

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I'm having an issue with using the package_facts module in Ansible. Basically, I just want to get the version of zabbix-agent installed as I need to do some stuff depending on which version is installed.

Now I got this in a playbook task:

```
- name: Gather Installed Packages Facts
  package_facts:
    manager: "auto"
  tags:
    - zabbix-check

- name: "Zabbix Found test result"
  debug: var=ansible_facts.packages['zabbix-agent']
  when: "'zabbix-agent' in ansible_facts.packages"
  tags:
    - zabbix-check

- name: "Zabbix Not-found test result"
  debug: 
    msg: "Zabbix NOT found"
  when: "'zabbix-agent' not in ansible_facts.packages"
  tags:
    - zabbix-check
```

Which spits out something like this:

```
ok: [vm3] => {
    "ansible_facts.packages['zabbix-agent']": [
        {
            "arch": "x86_64", 
            "epoch": null, 
            "name": "zabbix-agent", 
            "release": "1.el7", 
            "source": "rpm", 
            "version": "4.0.10"
    ]
}
ok: [vm4] => {
    "ansible_facts.packages['zabbix-agent']": [
        {
            "arch": "x86_64", 
            "epoch": null, 
            "name": "zabbix-agent", 
            "release": "1.el7", 
            "source": "rpm", 
            "version": "3.2.11"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get the value of that "Version": "3.2.11" so that I can store that in a variable and use that later. I've seen that post using yum and doing some json query but that won't work for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For some reason (probably because of more versions of the same package might be installed), the value of the package dictionary is a **list**. A simple solution is to take the first element

```yaml
- set_fact:
    za_ver: "{{ ansible_facts.packages['zabbix-agent'][0].version }}"
  when: "'zabbix-agent' in ansible_facts.packages"
```

- To take into the account the possibility of more versions installed, use the [map](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#map) filter

```yaml
- set_fact:
    za_ver: "{{ ansible_facts.packages['zabbix-agent']|
                map(attribute='version')|
                list }}"
  when: "'zabbix-agent' in ansible_facts.packages"
```

- Below is the equivalent with the [json_query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) filter

```yaml
- set_fact:
    za_ver: "{{ ansible_facts.packages['zabbix-agent']|
                json_query('[].version') }}"
  when: "'zabbix-agent' in ansible_facts.packages"
```

- Optionally, to sort the versions, add the filter [community.general.version_sort](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/version_sort_filter.html#ansible-collections-community-general-version-sort-filter) to the pipe.

Comment: Thanks this served for my purpose!

Answer (score 1):

Is there a way to debug if the version matches a specific value?

```
  - set_fact:
      pkg_ver: "{{ ansible_facts.packages['{{ item.package_name }}'][0].version }}"
    loop: "{{ lookup('dict', packagesToValidate) }}"
    when: "'{{ item.package_name }}' in ansible_facts.packages" and inventory_hostname in item.hosts
```

being packagesToValidate a dictionary containing hosts, version and package name to validate?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use YUM to get the information for the package the and then isolation the version.

```
- name: YUM get package info
  ansible.builtin.yum:
    list: zabbix-agent
  register: yumoutput

- name: YUM Output
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ yumoutput.results | map(attribute='version') | list }}"
```